# Laravel login will not redirect after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authentication

Everyone.  I have been stuck with Laravel redirecting after login.  The connection works and after I login it redirects to a blank page but if I change the url path I can access the different web pages.  Any assistance would be highly appreciated!  I am using LDAP to connect and it is working.

[image: Route List]

On my AuthController I have the protected $redirectTo paths set.  See picture below.
[image]

Please let me know if there is any other code I should provide.

Thank you!!!

(RedirectIfAuthenticated.php)

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{

```
protected $auth;
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/computers/create');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

My Routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

Route::auth();
Route::get('login', 'LoginController@index');
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@check_password');
Route::patch('computers/{inventories}', 'InventoriesController@update');
Route::get('computers/search', 'InventoriesController@search');
Route::resource('computers', 'InventoriesController');
```

});
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

loginController.php

```
    <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
/**
 * @class Login
 */
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class Login extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
    public function check_password(Request $req)

    {
        //die('has to stop here');
        $user = User::check_password($req);
//var_dump($user); die;
        if ($user)
        {

            return redirect('/computers/create');
        }
        else
    {

            return redirect('login')->with('message', 'Login Failed');
        }
    }
}
```

AuthController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;


use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $redirectTo = '/computers/create';
    protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/login';
    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */


    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->auth = $auth;
        //$this->registrar = $registrar;

        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    //Using Ldap
//    protected function validator(array $data)
//    {
//        return Validator::make($data, [
//            'name' => 'required|max:255',
//            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
//            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
//        ]);
    //}
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    //Removed b/c LDAP is being usedcd
//    protected function create(array $data)
//    {
//        return User::create([
//            'name' => $data['name'],
//            'email' => $data['email'],
//            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
//        ]);
//    }
}
```

InventoriesController.php

```
  <?php

namespace  App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Inventory;
use App\Http\Requests\InventoryRequest;
class InventoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');  //does not allow users to login, redirects back to login when using LDAP credentials

    }
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $location = $request->input("building");
        if ($location != null) {
            $inventories = Inventory::where('building', $location)->get();
        }  else {
            $inventories = Inventory::all();
        }
        return view('computers.index', compact('inventories'));
    }
    public function show($inventories)
    {
        $inventories = Inventory::findOrFail($inventories);
        return view::make('computers.show')
            ->with('inventory', $inventories);
    }
    public function create(){
        //flash('Hello World', 'This is the message');
        return view('computers.create');
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  inventory  $request
     * @return Response
     *
     */
    public function store(InventoryRequest $request)
    {
           Inventory::create($request->all());
        flash('Success!', 'Inventory Successfully Updated!');
//s
//        return redirect()->back();  //temporary
        return back();
    }
    public function edit($inventories)
    {
        $inventories = Inventory::findOrFail($inventories);
        return view('computers.edit', compact('inventories'));
    }
    public function update(InventoryRequest $request, Inventory $inventories){
        $inventories->update($request->all());
        flash('Success!', 'Inventory Successfully Updated!');
        return back();
    }
    public function search()
        {
            $search = \Request::get('q'); //<-- we use global request to get the param of URI
//            $search = Input::get('search');
            $inventories = Inventory::where('lastName','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
               -> orwhere('firstName', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                -> orwhere('department', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                -> orwhere('building', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                -> orwhere('room', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                -> orwhere('manufacturer', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                -> orwhere('device', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                -> orwhere('model', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                -> orwhere('tag', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                -> orwhere('macAddress', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                -> orwhere('status', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                -> orwhere('comments', 'LIKE','%'.$search.'%' )
                ->get();
            return view('computers.search',compact('inventories'));
        }
}
```

Comment: Post your code, screenshots are not good enough.

Comment: Is it redirecting to the correct URL (/computers/create)? Do you see content  if you visit that URL manually? You didn't post your code for the InventoriesController, so it might just be that you're not returning the view correctly for that page.

Comment: Yes, Manually I can go to the links.

Comment: Never again show imgs please.

Answer (score 2):

Check the RedirectIfAuthenticated.php Middleware. It should look like this by default:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Make sure that what is returned is the good page!! If you don't have that Middleware maybe take a look at Laravel's doc to create one!

Comment: I also have it set there as well.  Still does not redirect.  Believe me I would not be here asking if I didn't try figuring it out.